# Alias command doesn't work under system function in c

Tags: c, alias

I'm trying to write an alias using C system function, here's the code

```
if (argc <= 3) {
    printf("Program Usage: ./executable alias > or < or >> or &\n");
}
else {
    if (strcmp(argv[1],"alias") == 0) {
        if (strcmp(argv[2], "redirect") == 0) {
            char y[] = "=\">\"";
            char *xs = strcat(argv[1], " ");
            char *x = strcat( xs, strcat(argv[3], y));
            printf("%s\n",x);
            int status = system(x);
            printf("%d\n", status);
        }
        else {
            printf("You've not entered proper symbol\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("You've not entered the shell property as alias\n");
    }
}
```

The general way of running the program is

```
./a.out alias redirect custom_alias_name
```

Moreover system function is returning 0 but when I check using alias command it doesn't shows the current alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, a call to `system()` will not modify the parent environment's state. A program when executed inherits the parent process's environment. This inherited environment copy is local to the child process. Any changes to this local environment are discarded once this child process exists.

Comment: @xkOder So you mean that after I run the program then the alias is working as needed but after the execution of the program is completed then it returns to its normal state.

Comment: @JayPrakashSarma Yes, exactly.

Comment: @xkOder Isn't there any way to reflect the aliasing changes even after the program exits?

Comment: No - _User-land_ Programs that want similar functionality, usually change `.bashrc` or similar start-up scripts depending on the platform (like `AUTOEXEC.BAT` on Windows) and place shell commands to modify the environment; and then ask for a system reboot. Or simply accomplish this via a shell-script directly. In _Bash_, you may source the shell-script so that its environment changes are reflected in current shell process. http://ss64.com/bash/period.html

Comment: To add further; For modifying the start-up script(s), the program in question must have appropriate permissions to do so.

Comment: Aliases are not stored in environment variables, but are stored in data structures internal to the shell.

Comment: @BatchyX - Correct! And those data structure(s) form part of the shell environment; I should not link to specifically the environment _variables_ part; removed it.

Answer (score -1):

The value returned is the status of the command, 0 for success and -1 for error; in this case system() returns 0!

Comment: system() return a value that should be interpreted like the status variable of wait(), or -1 if forking failed.

Comment: system() man page: The value returned is -1 on error and the return status of the command otherwise. I doesn't agree with your -1 !!!

Comment: The real system() man page: `The value returned is -1 on error (e.g., fork(2)  failed), and the return status of the command otherwise. This latter return status is in the format specified in wait(2). Thus, the exit code of the command will be WEXITSTATUS(status).`